# Multiple Databases configuration in doctrine symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am getting following exception while saving the entity.(Database names configured in config.yml file.)

> [{"message":"A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Seal\MdBundle\Entity\MdJournal#user'   that was not configured to
>   cascade persist operations for entity: test. Explicitly persist the
>   new entity     or configure cascading persist operations on the
>   relationship. If you cannot find out which entity causes   the problem
>   implement 'Seal\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\User#__toString()' to get
>   a clue.","class":"InvalidArgumentException"
>     ,"exceptionClassName":"InvalidArgumentException"}]

Comment: Either persist & flush the `user` oder cascade them. I don't see a problem with multiple object managers.

Answer (score 0):

Persist your entity user before MdJournal.

```
$user = new User();
$mdJournal = new MdJournal();
$mdJournal->setUser($user);
$em1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager("db1")
$em2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager("db2")
$em1->persist($user);
$em2->persist($mdJournal);
$em1->flush();
$em2->flush();
```

OR Add into OneToMany relation

```
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MdJournal", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"})
```

Comment: I have used cascade={"all"}..after that i am getting the following exception.                                                                                  [{"message":"Class Proxies\\SealOAuthServerBundleEntityRoleProxy is not a valid entity or mapped super
 class.","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\MappingException","exceptionClassName":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping
\\MappingException"}]

Comment: php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata &
      php app/console doctrine:schema:validate

Comment: For single database configuration it is working fine,Based on the user related data iam transfering to other database(DB details in config.yml).In php code -$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager("db");